# Change date in JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json, date

I have a few dates in my JSON file and I wonder how I can rewrite the output of them.

Current date: 2018-03-04T23:40:46.94
How it should be: 04/03/2018

Current JSON:

```
 {
    "SKU": "PQ-70-7EF",
    "ParentSKU": null,
    "Category": "Alarm clocks",
    "EAN": "4971850420019",
    "Title": "Casio Wakeup timers",
    "Description": "Casio Wakeup timers",
    "Brand": "CASIO",
    "RRP": 56,
    "Price": 26.1,
    "PriceUpdateUTC": null,
    "Stock": 0,
    "StockUpdateUTC": "2018-03-04T23:40:46.94",
    "Images": [
        {
            "ImageSort": null,
            "ImageURL": "https://uwt.blob.core.windows.net/dsales/partimage/pq-70-7ef_kniwoz.jpg",
            "IsDefault": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Current script:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $entry) {
    $data[$key]['StockUpdateUTC'] = date('d/m/Y');
}
```

The above script is changing all dates to today's date.
Thanks for the help.

Regards
Ely

Comment: Not certain why you would want to change that.  When it comes to dates, either persisting them or sending on a wire in some kind of API, you should prefer UTC (as in your actual format).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert the current string date to a timestamp (using [`strtotime()`](https://php.net/strtotime)) and then pass this timestamp as the second argument of [`date()`](https://php.net/date).

```
foreach ($data as $key => $entry) {
    $data[$key]['StockUpdateUTC'] = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($data[$key]['StockUpdateUTC']));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the date variable as a parameter in the `date()` function, like this:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $entry) {
    $data[$key]['StockUpdateUTC'] = date('d/m/Y',strtotime($data[$key]['StockUpdateUTC']));
 }
```

This way it will convert your date, instead of using the current one.

EDIT: As mencioned by Syscall, u need to convert your string to a actual date, using `strtotime()`

Comment: This is correct, but why not link the `date()` reference to the PHP documentation for reference?

Comment: This changes the date for all to: "StockUpdateUTC": "01/01/1970".

Comment: Need to use strtotime here like Syscall.

Comment: Yeah i forgot about that, apologies.